# Get the highest ID number in a SQL table , LINQ , C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

How can we get the highest ID number in an empty SQL table ?
e.g:
Assume we have a table with ten rows, but all of rows were deleted , now we wanna get the highest row's ID !!!

The below code throw an Exception because the table is empty :

```
var maxID = db.TableNames.Select(q => q.Id).Max();
```

Comment: You want the next automatically incrementing primary key, where there are no records currently existing in your dataset, correct?

Comment: I don't think you can implement with LINQ, but you can create a function and call that through LINQ.

Comment: @AD.Net : Could you please describe it more ?

Comment: Describe which part? You can invoke a sql function through LINQ quite easily. I'd probably do it that way, since I do not know if that's at all possible through LINQ alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server try [the IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) function.

Note that there can be gaps in identity value sequences because of failed transactions etc, so there is no guarantee that a row was ever committed with this value.

Comment: I'm not sure this functionality is exposed in any other manner.  However, I would assume this would be a good time to set up a stored proc which could be exposed via your LINQ to SQL ERM.

Comment: I wanna implement it with LINQ

Comment: I have a question, isn't the automatically incremented primary key for an empty table 1?If it isn't, how does the system decide the next auto incremented id(for int type)?

Comment: @Ateş GÜRAL :By adding IDENT_SEED to IDENT_CURRENT/0

Comment: I've used `public int GetLastNewsID()
{
    const string command = @"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('{0}') AS Current_Identity;";
    int id = EntityModel.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, "News");
    return id;
}` but it returns -1 whereas it must be return 4!!!

Comment: ExecuteStoreCommand returns the number of rows affected for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements, and -1 for other types of statements including yours.  You probably want to use ExecuteStoreQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
 IList<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 IList<int> emptyValues = new List<int> { };

 int max = values.DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MinValue)
                                    .Max();

 // do not throw exception
 int maxEmpty = emptyValues.DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MinValue)
                           .Max();

// max == 5
// maxEmpty == Int32.MinValue
```

**EDIT:**

My answer can help you get rid of exception in case of empty table but not the next auto increment value. You can follow Joe's answer and wrap `IDENT_CURRENT` function into a new stored procedure `GetIdentity` than call it using `LINQ`

```
var nextIdent = (from a in db.GetIdentity("TableName")) + 1;
```

Comment: Should note that this approach is ONLY valid if you're not using an auto-incrementing column of some kind.

Comment: Well, I wanna next automatically incrementing primary key, where there are no records currently existing in a dataset. Not Int32.MinValue

Comment: @Mohammad : you can not do this on client side, see Joe's answer for server side solution. My answer can help you get rid of exception in case of empty table but not next auto increment value

Comment: May I ask why you're using "IList<T>" as type for values and emptyValues? (I'm new to C# and I'd simply use "List<T>")

Comment: @wullxz : in this aprticular example this does not give us any prefferences, this is already as a common practice for me. This called Interface-based programming, interfaces gives more flexibility in terms of abstraction, you can substitute one class by another when refferencing it by an interface (both should implement a common interface). See http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/01/01/interface-based-programming.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If ID is an identity column, the following SQL will return what you're looking for. LINQ may not give you direct access to this function, in which case you'll need to run a simple DataReader.

```
USE DATABASENAME;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("TABLENAME", NORESEED);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do that as it sound like you are trying to do something hacky Anyway if the table is empty why don't you reset the Identity counter(If the Integrity reference allows you to do that) :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn INT IDENTITY (0, 1)
```

Comment: I wanna it to name an uploaded image according it's ID number in DB.

Comment: @Mohammad Insert it, read the value and then rename the file. You should probably mention that's what you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: If you want to reset the identity counter in a table in SQL Server, it's better to use DBCC CHECKIDENT with the RESEED argument. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not you are locked into your DB schema but this is a reason why people use GUIDs.  You may consider looking into that.