# ExecuteStoreCommand returns -1 , EntityFramework , C#?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, entity-framework, identity-column

I wanna get the next automatically incrementing primary key, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740511/get-the-highest-id-number-in-a-sql-table-linq-c) I understood to use T-SQL for doing that.
So I wrote the following  method :

```
public int GetLastNewsID()
{
    const string command = @"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('{0}') AS Current_Identity;";
    int id = EntityModel.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, "News");
    return id;
}
```

but it returns -1, whereas it must be 4 right now.

P.S:
When I execute below T-SQL in SQL Management Studio , it returns 4

```
USE T;
GO
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('NEWS') AS Current_Identity;
GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx)

```
public int GetLastNewsID()
{
    const string command = @"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ({0}) AS Current_Identity;";
    var id = EntityModel.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(command, "News").First();

    return Convert.ToInt32(id);
}
```

The SQL query will return a `decimal` so you need to convert it to `int`.

Comment: I've done it but I recive an Exception : `InvalidOperationException.The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Answer (score 0):

Read part about return value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx

Comment: Yes, ExecuteStoreCommand() returns the number of rows affected, so long as you have (the default) `set nocount off`. With `set nocount on` it returns -1.