# Executing SQL query that outputs (print) through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4

I was provided with an SQL query that outputs (PRINT) data neatly, the sticky part is that I need to execute it (and use the output later obviously) through my application which already makes use of EF4.1.

Here's what I have so far.

```
        string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
        _ctx.Connection.Open();
        DbCommand com = _ctx.Connection.CreateCommand();

        sqlQuery = @"declare @note varchar(1000)
                    set @note = (select
                    'Client: '+cast([NO_CLIENT] as varchar)+' - '+TABLE1.[nom]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Adr_1 '+[ADR_1]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Adr_2 '+[ADR_2]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Adr_3 '+[ADR_3]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Adr_4 '+[ADR_4]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Contact: '+[CONTACT]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Postal Code|Code Postal: '+substring([CODE_POSTAL],1,3)+' '+substring([CODE_POSTAL],4,3)+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Tel No: '+[TELEPHONE]+' Ext.: '+[POSTE_EXTENSION]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Fax No: '+[NO_FAX]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Clinic: '+[CLINIQUE_QUI_FACTURE]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Langu.: '+ case [LANGUE] when 1 then 'Fr' when 2 then 'En' Else 'N/A'  end+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    case [ACTIF] when 0 then 'Non-Active|Inactif' when 1 then 'Active|Actif' Else 'N/A' end+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Account Man.|Chargé Cpte: '+CAST(TABLE1.[NO_VENDEUR_1] AS VARCHAR)+' - '+clve.[NOM]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'DATE REGISTERED|DATE ENREGISTREMENT: '+[DATE_ENREGISTREMENT]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    '---------- MARKETING INFO ----------'+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Company|Cie: '+[TABLE2_NOM]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Contact: '+[TABLE2_CONTACT]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Tel.: '+[TABLE2_TELEPHONE]+
                    CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                    'Adr_1: '+[TABLE2_ADR1]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Adr_2: '+[TABLE2_ADR2]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Adr_3: '+[TABLE2_ADR3]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Adr-4: '+[TABLE2_ADR4]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'City|Ville: '+[TABLE2_VILLE_PROV]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Postal Code|Code Postal: '+substring([TABLE2_CODE_POSTAL],1,3)+' '+substring([TABLE2_CODE_POSTAL],4,3)+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Fax No: '+[TABLE2_FAX_1]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Ext.: '+[TABLE2_FAX_1_POSTE]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Fax 2 :'+[TABLE2_FAX_2]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Email1: '+[TABLE2_EMAIL1]+
                   CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
                   'Email2: '+[TABLE2_EMAIL2]

                    FROM TABLE1 
                        left join TABLE3 on TABLE1.no_vendeur_1 = TABLE3.no_vendeur
                        where [NO_CLIENT] = 2003)


                    print @note

                ";

        com.CommandText = @sqlQuery;
        DbDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
```

The query executes fine in SQL Management Studio, but I get this exception when the application runs it: (looks like it is parsing it somehow)

```
The query syntax is not valid. Near term '@note', line 1, column 14.
```

What do you think am I doing wrong ? (Probably everything lol)

Comment: "What do you think am I doing wrong ?" You're trying to present data through SQL instead of your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var r = _ctx.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(@sqlQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

The sqlQuery *declares* and *sets* value for **@note**, then *select*'s it in the end.

r will contain flat text.

This has pointed me in the right direction: [ExecuteStoreCommand returns -1 , EntityFramework , C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750587/executestorecommand-returns-1-entityframework-c)

Answer (score 2):

First, I pretty sure you cannot *Execute* a `Print` statement as a `SqlReader`.  I believe if you did the following it would work:

```
select @note =
```

Additionally, I would change your SQL Statement to look like (my preference):

```
select @note =
```

Instead of

```
set @note =
```

**Update 1**

So I did the following:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;
                     Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
{
  con.Open();
  using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, con))
  {
    string blah = @"declare @note varchar(1000) 
      set @note = 'asdf' 
      select @note";
    com.CommandText = blah;
    com.ExecuteReader();
  }
}
```

And it executes without issue.  So most likely there is either a problem on line 1 (as the error states), the DbCommand is parsing something incorrectly, or there is code you haven't provided that is changing the DbCommand.

Additionally, if you are using Entity Framework, *why completely by-pass it* instead of using it to create the same thing?

Comment: Same problem. Seems like DbDataReader is trying to parse it before sending to SQL since I don't see anything in SQL Profiler.

Comment: Why does your C# code look like `com.CommandText = @sqlQuery;` instead of `com.CommandText = sqlQuery;` (whats the @ sign for?)  And answer updated.

Comment: I've tried both without the @ and with. @ means literal so the compiler doesn't whine.

Comment: I would be glad if I knew a way to do it directly in LINQ/EF using the Context instead, but I don't think it's possible. Thanks for the update though.

Comment: Oh, I've tried this as well:

    var r = _ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand(@sqlQuery);

r is always null...